# Users, types and groups

Tags: sql

I'm just wondering is there better approach.

I have users in one system. However, there are few types. The point of having types is that each type has different additional data related to it. For example i have user types: students, professors, management and staff. Students have some additional info that professors don't have etc.

On the other side i have groups. For example,there is a group for each subject. So professor and student can be in same group concerning the subject.

My question, is this approach good enough for structuring data? Would that be better to not have different types of users but rather have user's group's data so that every user can belong to a group student or professors and that according to that, they can have more specific data?

Please help me to decide.

p.s. So right now i have this tables:

```
users (with type field)
students
professors
management
staff
groups (many groups, various and base for ACL)
```

Comment: See a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: great, so i was in a right path... seems like easiest.. bayme later on i can add in the system to create a table in a database if a "group" has additional dataset.. so all generic...

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to give a concrete answer to these abstract ideas. The correct design depends entirely on the details of the information system you are designing.

However, in general,

I'd define a `UserType` *entity* the has an `Id` and `Name` *attribute* and contains a row defining each *category* of `User`.

A `User` *entity* with an `Id` and every common *attribute* for every *category* of `User`. The `User` *entity* would have a foreign key to `UserType`.

Then a entity for each *category* of `User`: `Student`, `Professor` etc. Each *category* entity would have a foreign key to `User`. Each *category* entity would hold the *attributes* specific to its *category*.

Its entirley likely that there may be a deeper hierachy in your organization. For example, perhaps you need a category of `User` called `Lecturer` that is *categtorized* itself, perhaps into `DoctorialPostGraduate`, `Professor` etc., you get the idea.

A `Group` *entity* would have a `GroupUser` *relationship* associating many `Group` with many `User`.

---

There are other ways to do this but this approach normailizes your data and helps to reduce redundancy and is well supported by modern RDBMS.